# Make sudoers work with only certain parameter?

Tags: sudo

I'm trying to make my sudoers file allow a user to adjust the backlight without having to enter in the password. This is what I have:

```
# User alias specification
Cmnd_Alias ADJBL = /usr/bin/su -c "echo 150 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"

# For our user..
ouruser HOME=(root) NOPASSWD:ADJBL
```

.. but it doesn't seem to be working, I still get prompted for the password when I try and run that command with sudo. Apparently there is something I'm missing here, any ideas?

Comment: I assume that the alias is evaluated by the shell before the sudo rules are tested - ie, as written you would have to permit no-password access to /usr/bin/su - not ideal.

Comment: what would be a better way of accomplishing my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make a script and then let the use execute the script wthout password.

**Edit:**

sudoers:

`#User alias specification
Cmnd_Alias ADJBL = script.sh`

`#For our user..
ouruser HOME=(root) NOPASSWD:ADJBL`

then into the script:

`#!/bin/bash`

`sudo echo 150 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

anf add it to path. this should work.

Comment: how do you mean? the issue is that I cannot use that command without sudo, I want to use this command in a script, this is the reason that I'm trying to add it to sudoers

Comment: Evan, I edited my answer to explain myself better.